# Laravel - Column not found, when it exists in database

Tags: php, laravel, validation, registration

I'm trying to register a class of users (customers), and I'm currently hitting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `name` = john123)
```

The column does exist in the database table 'customers', additionally this SQL query laravel has generated looks odd?
**Register Controller:**

```
protected function createCustomer(Request $request)
    {
        // dd($request->all());
        // $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => ['required', 'alpha_dash', 'string', 'max:25', 'unique:users'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            $messages = $validator->messages();
            return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
            foreach($errors->all() as $error) {
            echo $error;
        }
        }
        elseif ($validator->passes())
        {
            $customer = customer::create([
                'name' => $request['name'],
                'email' => $request['email'],
                'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
            ]);
            return redirect()->intended('login/customer');
        }
    }
```

**Routes:**

```
Route::post('/register/customer', 'Auth\RegisterController@createCustomer')->name('customer.submit');
```

**register.blade.php:**

```
<form method="POST" action='{{ route("$url.submit") }}' aria-label="{{ __('Register') }}">

                        <p>{{ route("venue.submit") }}</p>
                       <!--  <p style="position: relative; bottom: 50px;">{{ $url }}</p> -->
                       @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                            <div>
                               {{$error}}
                            </div>
                       @endforeach
                    @else
                     <form method="POST" action="{{ route('venue.submit') }}" aria-label="{{ __('Register') }}">
                    @endisset
                        @csrf

...etc
```

**Users:**

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'username' => ['required', 'alpha_dash', 'string', 'max:25', 'unique:users'],
            'fname' => ['required', 'alpha', 'string', 'max:15'],
            'lname' => ['required', 'alpha', 'string', 'max:15'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
            // $profile = new profile();
            // $profile->user_id = $data[''];
        return User::create([
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'lname' => $data['lname'],
            'fname' => $data['fname'],
            'email' => $data['email'],

            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

Any help would be so awesome! Thankyou :)

Comment: Can we see your table?

Comment: does name column exists in your user table?

Comment: I'm trying to use my customers table, so no it doesn't, how do I force it to use my customers table?

Comment: I just updated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are validating unique in your users table which doesn't have the name column. So its giving you the error. Use customers table instead.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => ['required', 'alpha_dash', 'string', 'max:25', 'unique:customers'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:customers'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error says that column not found in `users` table and you have mentioned that column exist in `customers` table.

Please verify that you have used `protected $table = 'tableName';` property or not, if used then check correct table name is specified or not.